# How to disable/ lock one page in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want lock / disable one particular page(fragment) in viewpager. According to scenario for some people only able to access that page. How restrict swiping to that page.

[image]

I disabled tab click for Events page by using following code :

```
    LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
if(!isAccess){
            tabStrip.getChildAt(3).setClickable(false);
            tabStrip.getChildAt(3).setEnabled(false);
}
```

But now I need to restrict swiping for that page in view pager. How to do this?

Comment: locking one tab seems to be pretty bad UX. Why not just have a simple page that says events are unavailable (or some relevant message) when the user swipes to the events tab?

Comment: Better idea would be only show available options according to the user. I.e. if user has access to Event tab, render 4 tabs else render only 3 tabs.

Comment: this code not working, it returs null: LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I written this in pager adapter it works.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
  if(!isAccess) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 4;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not according to OP's requirement. If he implements this code, only 3 tabs will get rendered in TabStrip also and _Event_ tab won't get even visible on screen.
OP wants to just disable/lock last tab.

Comment: It seems that your question doesn't match with your answer. You want to disable/lock tab but in your answer the 4th tab will not visible. Its static kind of static solution.

Comment: Yes this what I want. the 4th tab will be rendered  / visible according to scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == 3)
   {
     // show dialog that you are not allowed
      viewPager.setSelected(2);
   }  
}
});
```

Hope this helped you

You can also use

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

// optional 
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

// optional 
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) { }

// optional 
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
});
```

Comment: viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()  is depecated.

Comment: setSelected has the signature `public void setSelected(boolean selected)`, so calling it with 2 should be the same as calling it with false, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is also the solution without using the deprecated method (setOnPageChangeListener).

```
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);

            if(position == 3) {
                //To disable specific tab and set the previuos tab
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); //We cannot provide the position in setSelected(boolean) now. This was missed in above solution
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the first tab position

```
int currentTab = 0;
```

then make listener for viewPager

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //4 is the position of the tab we want to disable
                if (position == 4) {
                    if (currentTab < 4) {
                        // swipe from left to right
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
                        currentTab = 5;
                    } else {
                        // swipe from right to left 
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        currentTab = 3;
                    }
                } else {
                    currentTab = position;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop specific tab from being selected just use customized `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` you can even use the tab for other purposes this way.

```
    public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private float initialXValue;
    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            initialXValue = event.getX();
        return this.isSwipeAllowed(event) && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
    private boolean isSwipeAllowed(MotionEvent event) {
        //you can prevent any swipe from right to left for an item at a specified index, in your case getCurrentItem() returns 3 for Event tab 
        return getCurrentItem()!=3 || event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || (event.getX() - initialXValue) > 0;
    }
    }
```

**Custom TabLayout**

```
    public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectTab(Tab tab, boolean updateIndicator) {
        // it doesn't allow the item on index 3 to be selected in anyway
        if (!(tab.getPosition() == 3))
            super.selectTab(tab, updateIndicator);
    }
}
```