# How to disable viewPager scrolling after a certain button is clicked in one of the fragments?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I have made a tabbed activity with 2 tabs, one for login and one for register. Each of these tabs are designed in their own fragments.

I want that whenever login or register button is clicked from within the fragment, the viewPager should not be scrollable anymore till the network call is being executed.

What is the best method to do so? Is it possible to do this without defining a customized viewpager class?

It would be fine with me if the complete layout freezes or the activity stops taking any type of touch or swap inputs for the aforementioned duration.

Comment: You can use a **non-cancelable dialog**, which will shown on top of the screen until the network response something. use `.setCancelable(true)` on ProgressDialog.

Comment: This solution it may help for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873326/how-to-disable-lock-one-page-in-viewpager/37873614#37873614)

Comment: @lRadha Yes that is exactly what I should do. But for this project, I'll be using transparent view. But for future uses, I'll definitely go for non-cancelable dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon tapping the button, You  can add a transparent View above the ViewPager and set ClickListener to that View. Then all your touches will be consumed by that transparent View. After the network response comes, remove the transparent View.

Comment: Best solution if you want to disable swipe at both directions, no need to write custom viewpager.

Comment: I dont consider this as the best solution. If you write a custom viewpager, that viewpager can be re used at many layouts. but in this method, you have to add the transparent view in all the layouts. custom viewpager improves readability and maintainability of the code, because all the enabling and disabling of viewpager goes into the viewpager itself. those logics wont clutter in your Activity or fragment.

Comment: since the question was "Is it possible to do this without defining a customized viewpager class", I have answered that transparent view solution. and also there are already tons of custom viewpager solutions in stackoverflow.

Comment: yeah, i myself have used custom viewpager, for disabling in both direction and or in either direction. You are right though, it will be a good fit if it had to be used at one or 2 places or else it doesn't makes sense to create a new class and do it.

Comment: @DineshBob Thanks for the answer. This is surely one of the best solutions for my case since there is only this activity where this feature is required, and the app is to be made for a simple project and not for production use. Also this solution will reduce my burden to write extra code for custom viewPager.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be fine with me if the complete layout freezes or the activity stops taking any type of touch or swap inputs for the aforementioned duration.

I think you need a [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)
to show the progress and call it's [setCancelable(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)) and when your background task is finished dismiss() the dialog

Comment: Yes, actually that is what I need. But since I have already implemented everything with progressLayout, I would prefer doing it using a transparent view as suggested by @Dinesh Bob rather than changing the code.